# Vue.js getting an element within a component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a component, how can I select one of its elements?

I'm trying to get an input that is within this component's template.

There could be multiple components so the `querySelector` must only parse the current instance of the component.

```js
Vue.component('somecomponent', {
    template: '#somecomponent',
    props: [...],

   ...

    created: function() {
        somevariablehere.querySelector('input').focus();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 152, accepted):

There's a few options depending on what you're trying to access:

- You can access the child components of a Vue.js component with `this.$children`
- You can label specific DOM elements inside your template using `ref="uniqueName"` and refer to these later via `this.$refs.uniqueName`
  (but remember that you won't be able to refer to these until the component/app has [finished mounting](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted) and performed an initial render)
- If you're unable to label your elements, you can query the DOM for child elements using a CSS selector via `this.$el.querySelector('.myClass > .childElement')`
  (as above, the component/app needs to have [finished mounting](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted))

You can also explore by doing a simple `console.log(this)` inside your component and it will show you all the properties of your Vue component instance.

Comment: Hint: `this.$el` is undefined until mounted. If you want to initialize a variable do it in `mount()`

Answer (score 187):

## vuejs 2

`v-el:el:uniquename` has been replaced by `ref="uniqueName"`. The element is then accessed through `this.$refs.uniqueName`.

Comment: This helped me realize that the `ref` attribute works on any HTML element or Vue component. Good stuff.

Comment: It looks like this.$refs.uniqueName is an array, so you need to  this.$refs.uniqueName[0] to get the referenced element.

Comment: only after the mounting component , which could be done in the parent's mounted method : https://medium.com/@brockreece/vue-parent-and-child-lifecycle-hooks-5d6236bd561f

Comment: Why has this been labeled as vuejs 2? It also works in vue.js 3.

Comment: @PassivProgrammer because if you're using the Composition API / Vue 3 best practice you don't have access to this.$refs (this is void)

Answer (score 60):

The answers are not making it clear:

Use **`this.$refs.someName`**, but, in order to use it, you must **add `ref="someName"` in the parent**.

See demo below.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mounted: function() {
    var childSpanClassAttr = this.$refs.someName.getAttribute('class');
    
    console.log('<span> was declared with "class" attr -->', childSpanClassAttr);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  Parent.
  <span ref="someName" class="abc jkl xyz">Child Span</span>
</div>
```

## `$refs`  and `v-for`

Notice that when used in conjunction with `v-for`, the `this.$refs.someName`  will be an array:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    ages: [11, 22, 33]
  },
  mounted: function() {
    console.log("<span> one's text....:", this.$refs.mySpan[0].innerText);
    console.log("<span> two's text....:", this.$refs.mySpan[1].innerText);
    console.log("<span> three's text..:", this.$refs.mySpan[2].innerText);
  }
})
```

```css
span { display: inline-block; border: 1px solid red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.13/dist/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  Parent.
  <div v-for="age in ages">
    <span ref="mySpan">Age is {{ age }}</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also important to note that reffed items are NOT reactive.

Answer (score 42):

In **Vue2** be aware that you can access **this.$refs.uniqueName** only after mounting the component.

Comment: Everything before mounted in Vue's lifecycle is not presented in your browser. Since it hasn't been mounted yet, there is no DOM available inspection.

Answer (score 7):

## Vue 2.x

**For Official information:**

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#v-el-and-v-ref-replaced

**A simple Example:**

On any Element you have to add an attribute `ref` with a **unique value**

```
<input ref="foo" type="text" >
```

To target that elemet use `this.$refs.foo`

```
this.$refs.foo.focus(); // it will focus the input having ref="foo"
```

Answer (score 7):

### Composition API

[Template refs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-template-refs.html) section tells how this has been unified:

- within template, use `ref="myEl"`; `:ref=` with a `v-for`
- within script, have a `const myEl = ref(null)` and expose it from `setup`

The reference carries the DOM element from mounting onwards.

Comment: so performing a query like `document.querySelectorAll("nav > ul > li");` is out of the question?

Comment: No it's not. But there you start the query from document, the root. Since you are making a component, it should likely start from a node within the component.

Comment: ok so something like `<header ref="headerEL">`, where header is a parent of nav, then `const headerEl = ref<HTMLElement>()`, then you can do `const links = headerEl.value.querySelectorAll('nav > ul > li')`

Comment: (tips) add `await nextTick();` before invoking `myEl` to ensure component is fully rendered.