# How to use angular.element() in Vue

Tags: angularjs, vue.js

I used like this in angularjs before. And now I m moving to Vuejs.
How can it be replaced in Vuejs?

```
 angular.element(document.querySelector('.popup-inner#company-etc')).css('display', 'none');
```

Comment: Using DOM like in jQuery was a bad practice in AngularJS, so it is in Vue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$refs`

```
<div ref="companyEtc" class="popup-inner" ...

...

this.$refs.companyEtc.style.display = "none"
```

I would advise to use conditional rendering: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html

You also can find more information about getting element in a component in answers to the question: [Vue.js getting an element within a component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37104304/vuejs-getting-an-element-within-a-component)