# VueJS references in a component don't work

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Here is a very cut down version of my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="file:///D:/OtherWork/javascript/vue/vue.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <Dial style="width: 120px; height: 120px;" v-model="src_value"></Dial>
        </div>

        <script>
            Vue.component('Dial', {
                template: '<canvas ref="dial_canvas"></canvas>',
                data: function () {
                    return {
                        value: 0,
                        centre: { x: 0, y: 0 },
                        canvas: null
                    }
                },
                props: ['value'],
                mounted: function() {
                    console.log(this.$refs.dial_canvas);
                },
                render: function() {
                    // TODO: Draw on canvas here.
                }
            });

            var app = new Vue({
                el: '#app',
                data: {
                    src_value: -1
                },
                created() {
                }
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I run this and look at the console log, `this.$refs.dial_canvas` is undefined.

I have read a variety of questions about this. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37104304/vuejs-getting-an-element-within-a-component) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40884194/vuejs-cant-access-refs-from-component) both say that the mistake was trying to access `$refs` (and `$el`) inside `created()` rather than `mounted()` but that isn't my mistake (or it was but I fixed it).

I have found various articles about using references in a component, but without exception they all use ".vue" files and have some weird syntax I don't understand to import components...which doesn't work for me. It looks like they are using some server side magic and I don't want that. I need (really need) to be able to keep the web server as simple as possible - just plain old text files served from the simplest of web servers.

I need my component to be re-usable so I can have multiple on a page all displaying different values.

How can I access the refs in my component while keeping it as simple as possible?

P.s. `$el` also used to point to the `<canvas>` element (before I made some changes), but it too is undefined.

Comment: You can't have both a `template` and a `render` function, it's one or the other.

Comment: Just to be clear, the `template` is going to be ignored because you have a `render` function. As the `render` function doesn't return anything your component won't create any elements.

Comment: I was following the example here: https://alligator.io/vuejs/vue-html5-canvas/

Comment: Can you tell me how I can achieve what I want, namely a component that is actually a canvas and that draws to itself.

Comment: Also, please put your comment as an answer so I can accept it, preferably with some clues as to how to overcome my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @skirtle says, you cannot have a render function and a template. In fact I found that with an empty render function, Vue replaces the element with an empty comment.

I also found that capital letters in the component name caused issues.

The solution for me was to replace my render function as a method like this:

```
methods: {
    setValue: function(value) {
        this.value = value;
        // TODO: Draw on canvas here.
    }
},
```

I also added a `ref` to the entry in the template and when the value updated used the `ref` to get the component and used my new `setValue` method to both set the internal value and redraw the canvas to represent that value.